# jQuery selector optimisation : sizzle / pseudo / hidden

Tags: jquery-selectors

I used Visual Studio 2010 excellent javascript profiler to profile the javascript of a web page on Internet Explorer.
(Analyze / Launch perf wizard / Instrumentation / JS application / profile js + url of page)

The perf report shows that jQuery's sizzle is the cause of the slowness (ie: some jquery selectors on my web page).

It shows the time spent is in Sizzle > filter > hidden > PSEUDO.
I do not have any selector with :hidden, so i don't understand why it looses this much time in hidden.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4
I tried with jQuery 1.5 and it is the same.

Comment: the `:visible` selector uses the `:hidden` selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `:visible` calls `:hidden` so if you're using that, it will show in the profiler.

Also note, that on the jQuery doc for the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector it mentions

> Because :hidden is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :hidden cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. **To achieve the best performance when using :hidden to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":hidden")**.